# how to add NSDictionary in row of table on sqlite DataBase

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsdictionary

I am new in iphone development. I want to store one NSDictionary in row of table sqlite.
I googled and found many result but it does not work for me.

this is my dictionary :

```
NSDictionary * dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"24",@"id",@"Folder",@"name",@"300 MB",@"size", nil];
```

also I searched in this site but I don't understand any thing in similar posts.
please explain me more about add (store) NSDictionary in row of table SQLite DB.

Comment: You'll need to encode the dictionary (as `JSON` or a `plist` perhaps) and store that in the database.

Comment: my fiend I can encode this dictionary to plist but how to store that (plist) in database???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by creating a table having three columns (Using create table query) . And then insert these objects from your dictionary into those columns(Using insert query).

Edit : For inserting data use query :

```
            NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tablename (column1, column2,column3) values('%@','%@','%@')",[dic objectForKey:@"id"],[dic objectForKey:@"name"],[dic objectForKey:@"size"]];
            NSLog(@"query : %@",query);
            [self executeQuery:query];
```

In .h class make an sqlite instance :

```
sqlite3 *database; and import:  #import<sqlite3.h>
```

In .m class make an add these methods :

```
-(NSString *) dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"PATH %@",[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DatabaseName]);
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DatabaseName];
}

/*==================================================================
              METHOD FOR INSERTING DATA IN DATABASE
 ==================================================================*/
-(void)executeQuery:(NSString *)query
{
    //NSLog(@"QUERY : %@",query);

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"query Statement Not Compiled");
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Data not Opened");
    }
}
```

For Reading data :

```
/*==================================================================
 METHOD FOR Fetching Data FROM DATABASE
 ==================================================================*/
 NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from table_name"];
NSMutableArray *tableData = [self fetchingDataFromTable:query];
```

// Here table data array contains all records

```
-(NSMutableArray *)fetchingDataFromTable:(NSString *)query;
{
    NSLog(@"QUERY : %@",query);

    NSString *idToReturn=@"";
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *temp= [NSMutableDictionary new];
                const char *s;


                s=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
                if(s==NULL)
                {
                    idToReturn=@"";
                }
                else
                {
                    idToReturn =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
                }
                [temp setObject:idToReturn forKey:@"id"];

                s=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
                if(s==NULL)
                {
                    idToReturn=@"";
                }
                else
                {
                    idToReturn =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
                }
                [temp setObject:idToReturn forKey:@"name"];

                s=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
                if(s==NULL)
                {
                    idToReturn=@"";
                }
                else
                {
                    idToReturn =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
                }
                [temp setObject:idToReturn forKey:@"size"];

                if (temp != nil)
                {
                    [returnArray addObject:temp];

                    temp = nil;
                }

            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
    }
    return returnArray;

}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thank you dear friend. I create table DB with three columns with names (id , name , size) and this level what I do??? can you explain me more about (Using insert query) with code!!! thank you very much.

Comment: my friend I give this error "query Statement Not Compiled" why?

Comment: do it.thank you my friend I have one question!!! with this way can add many NSDictionary in table sqlite???

Comment: also how read this data from sqlite?? thank you very much if answer two question master... :-*

Comment: Yes you can add as many as you need. You can use loop and then use insert query for inserting repeatedly.

Comment: my friend I add this code in my application . how to understand read from sqlite??? store in NSMutableArray *returnArray???

Comment: WoW!!! Dear friend I so confused !!! what I do that once store (when first run app) this NSDictionary in table sqlite and After a series of check data if exist in sqlite not add...

Comment: @NishantTyagi
I'm getting this error "query Statement Not Compiled" why? 
Can you please suggest me what I am doing wrong 
 I create table DB with three columns with names (id , name , size).

Comment: @NishantTyagi
Alos i am getting empty data when I am faching I am using same code.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)executeQuery:(NSString *)query
{
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
        const char *tail;
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1, &stmt, &tail);
        if (stmt == NULL)
                return nil;

        int status;
        int num_cols;
        int i;
        int j = 1;
        int type;
        id obj;
        NSString *key;
        NSMutableArray *result;
        NSMutableDictionary *row,*roww;
        j = 0;
        result = [NSMutableArray array];
      roww = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        while ((status = sqlite3_step(stmt)) != SQLITE_DONE) {

                if (status != SQLITE_ROW)
                {

                        continue;
                }
                else
                {
                row = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                num_cols = sqlite3_data_count(stmt);
                for (i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
                        obj = nil;
                        type = sqlite3_column_type(stmt, i);
                        switch (type) {
                        case SQLITE_INTEGER:
                                obj = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, i)];
                                break;
                        case SQLITE_FLOAT:
                                obj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:sqlite3_column_double(stmt, i)];
                                break;
                        case SQLITE_TEXT:
                                obj = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_text(stmt, i)];
                                break;
                        case SQLITE_BLOB:
                                obj = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, i)
                                    length:sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, i)];
                                break;
                        case SQLITE_NULL:
                                obj = [NSNull null];
                                break;
                        default:
                                break;
                        }

                        key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_name(stmt, i)];
                        [row setObject:obj forKey:key];
                }

            NSString *keyq = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j];
            [roww setObject:row forKey:keyq];
            j++;
                    [roww setValue:@"1" forKey:@"Success"];

        }

        }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

   // NSLog(@"%@",roww);
    return roww;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And get data into dictionary from table in iOS:

```
-(void)getData:(NSString *) tablename
{
    NSMutableDictionary * tabledata= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString *str = @"select * from ";
    NSString *strQuery = [str stringByAppendingString:tablename];
    tabledata = [db executeQuery:strQuery];

    NSDictionary *dic = [tabledata valueForKey:@"0"];
    NSLog(@"dic is:%@",dic);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created dynamic code which will return list of all columns with all rows

```
 -(NSMutableDictionary*)getRowsFromTableName:(NSString*)tableName
 {
 NSString *databasePath =[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
//                         stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"sqlcipher.db"];
 sqlite3 *db;
 bool sqlcipher_valid = NO;
 NSMutableDictionary *dbData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 NSMutableArray *columnList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
    const char* key = [keyString UTF8String];
    sqlite3_key(db, key, strlen(key));
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, (const char*) "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "PRAGMA cipher_version;", -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            if(sqlite3_step(stmt)== SQLITE_ROW) {
                const unsigned char *ver = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
                if(ver != NULL) {
                    sqlcipher_valid = YES;

                    // password is correct (or database initialize), and verified to be using sqlcipher
                    char *errMsg;
                    const char *query = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from %@",tableName] UTF8String]; //where name = 'abc'";
                    if (sqlite3_exec(db, query, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)
                        != SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        // isSuccess = NO;
                        NSLog(@"Failed to open data into table");
                        [dbData setValue:@"Failed to open data into table" forKey:@"Message"];
                        [dbData setValue:@"Failed" forKey:@"status"];
                        return dbData;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Data open Successfully");
                        int num_cols;
                        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                            while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
                            {
                                num_cols = sqlite3_data_count(stmt);
                                NSMutableDictionary *columnDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                                for (int i = 1; i < num_cols; i++) {
                                    NSString *colValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, i)];
                                    NSString *colName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_name(stmt, i)];
                                    [columnDic setValue:colValue forKey:colName];
                                    NSLog(@"%@",columnDic);
                                }
                                [columnList addObject:columnDic];
                                columnDic = nil;
                            }
                            NSLog(@"%@",columnList);
                            [dbData setValue:columnList forKey:@"data"];

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error while binding variable. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                [dbData setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error while binding variable. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db)] forKey:@"Message"];
                [dbData setValue:@"Failed" forKey:@"status"];
                return dbData;
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            [dbData setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db)] forKey:@"Message"];
            [dbData setValue:@"Failed" forKey:@"status"];
            return dbData;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        [dbData setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db)] forKey:@"Message"];
        [dbData setValue:@"Failed" forKey:@"status"];
        return dbData;
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
NSLog(@"%@",dbData);

return dbData;
```

}